# YouTube playlist not showing up on some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, playlist

I have a youtube script that is working great on some browsers. I paid some make this and  realisted that not working like on iOS 12.4 or less and some other browsers. The problem that is creating the frame (DIV) for the list and nothing shows up. Can someone help me please.  Here is the site where I place it https://www.sheffieldvoices.org.uk/videos.

Thank you.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var key = "AIzaSyA........";
    var playlistId = "PLv6hpU.........";
    var URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems";

    var options = {
      part: "snippet",
      key: key,
      maxResults: 20,
      playlistId: playlistId,
    };

    loadVids();

    function loadVids() {
      $.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
        var id = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
        // mainVid(id);
        resultsLoop(data);
      });
    }

    function mainVid(id) {
      insertYTModal();
      addEventListenersToYTModal();
      $("#yt_video_hay").html(`
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              `);
    }

    function insertYTModal() {
      $("body").append(`<div class="modal" id="yt_modal_hay">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
    <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
      <button class="modal-close modal-toggle">x</button>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <section id="yt_video_hay"></section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`);
    }
    function removeYTModal() {
      $("#yt_modal_hay").remove();
    }
    function resultsLoop(data) {
      // debugger;

      $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
        var title = item.snippet.title;
        var desc = item.snippet.description.substring(0, 100);
        var vid = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

        $(".list-wrapper_hay").append(`
                          <div class="item" data-key="${vid}">

                              <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
                              <div class="details">
                                  <h4>${title}</h4>
                                  <p>${desc}</p>
                              </div>

                          </div>
                      `);
      });
    }

    // CLICK EVENT
    $(".list-wrapper_hay").on("click", "div", function () {
      var id = $(this).attr("data-key");
      mainVid(id);
      setTimeout(() => {
        $("#yt_modal_hay").toggleClass("is-visible");
      }, 100);
    });

    function addEventListenersToYTModal() {
      $(".modal-toggle").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (
          document.querySelector("#yt_modal_hay").classList[1] === "is-visible"
        ) {
          // debugger;
          removeYTModal();
        }
        $("#yt_modal_hay").toggleClass("is-visible");
      });
    }
  });
```

```
<div class="list-wrapper_hay"></div>
```

```
.list-wrapper_hay {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .list-wrapper_hay::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
  }
  .list-wrapper_hay::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }

  .list-wrapper_hay .item .details h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .list-wrapper_hay .item .details p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #cecece;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }

  .list-wrapper_hay .item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .list-wrapper_hay .item:hover {
    background: #737373;
  }
  .list-wrapper_hay .thumb {
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none !important;
    background: none !important;
    line-height: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    position: static !important;
  }

  .list-wrapper_hay .details {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    height: 75px;
  }

  /* 
  Modal 
*/
  #yt_modal_hay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000; /* 1 */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #yt_modal_hay.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  #yt_modal_hay .modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  }

  #yt_modal_hay.is-visible .modal-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }

  #yt_modal_hay .modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 6px;
  }

  #yt_modal_hay .modal-content {
    padding: 10px;
  }

  #yt_modal_hay .modal-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -20px;
    color: #000;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  #yt_video_hay iframe {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #yt_modal_hay .modal-wrapper {
      width: 80%;
    }
    #yt_video_hay iframe {
      height: 500px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #yt_video_hay iframe {
      height: 330px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    #yt_modal_hay .modal-wrapper {
      width: 95%;
    }
    #yt_video_hay iframe {
      height: 185px;
    }
    .list-wrapper_hay .item .details h4 {
          font-size: 1em;
    }
  }
```

Comment: check the browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: No error are showing checked in firefox developer tools., Found a error in other script, I taken that out see if the made a diffents.  Still the same not showing up.

Comment: so, firefox is where it doesn't work?